# I want to login to the local modem but the return value is just "Waiting..."

Tags: c#, authentication, modem

I want to login and see the wifi devices connected to the modem but the return value is just "Waiting..."
I can't set the cookie because it skips the login screen fast. Do I have to wait for additional time or is there another way I can wait until I get the information I want?

```
string url = "http://192.168.1.1/login.cgi";
                Uri address = new Uri(url);
                var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName", "admin"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PassWord", "aGNzNTQzNio%3D")
                };
                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    UseCookies = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false
                };
                var client = new HttpClient(handler)
                {
                    BaseAddress = address,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                };
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

```
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1">
        <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma" />
        <title>Waiting...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pageName = '/';
            top.location.replace(pageName);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>`
```

I see ajax page in developer tools (http://192.168.1.1/asp/GetRandCount.asp)

result always unique eg: fb1d2129bc3b7a3ebf28877fc6e69baa1d3a2847caf7e4c3

Total XHR Output is:

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      "name": "WebInspector",
      "version": "537.36"
    },
    "pages": [],
    "entries": [
      {
        "_initiator": {
          "type": "script",
          "stack": {
            "callFrames": [
              {
                "functionName": "send",
                "scriptId": "17",
                "url": "http://192.168.1.1/resource/common/jquery.min.js?202203162138140159067425",
                "lineNumber": 1,
                "columnNumber": 82612
              },
              {
                "functionName": "ajax",
                "scriptId": "17",
                "url": "http://192.168.1.1/resource/common/jquery.min.js?202203162138140159067425",
                "lineNumber": 1,
                "columnNumber": 78222
              },
              {
                "functionName": "LoginSubmit",
                "scriptId": "18",
                "url": "http://192.168.1.1/",
                "lineNumber": 458,
                "columnNumber": 2
              },
              {
                "functionName": "onclick",
                "scriptId": "47",
                "url": "http://192.168.1.1/",
                "lineNumber": 1326,
                "columnNumber": 206
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "_priority": "VeryHigh",
        "_resourceType": "xhr",
        "cache": {},
        "connection": "94621",
        "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "url": ".",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": "Cookie=sid=7a2fdeb886ed7ad2e8d82fb03ae9146090c19ed33cfea5326487c6b4bdaece9c:Language:turkish:id=1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "192.168.1.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "http://192.168.1.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "http://192.168.1.1/"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-Requested-With",
              "value": "XMLHttpRequest"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": "sid=7a2fdeb886ed7ad2e8d82fb03ae9146090c19ed33cfea5326487c6b4bdaece9c:Language:turkish:id=1",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "192.168.1.1",
              "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": false
            }
          ],
          "headersSize": 542,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "OK",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Cache-control",
              "value": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "Keep-Alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Security-Policy",
              "value": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Pragma",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "Transfer-Encoding",
              "value": "chunked"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-Frame-Options",
              "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-XSS-Protection",
              "value": "1; mode=block"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 51,
            "mimeType": "text/html",
            "compression": -11
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 304,
          "bodySize": 62,
          "_transferSize": 366,
          "_error": null
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "192.168.1.1",
        "startedDateTime": "2023-03-20T16:30:38.369Z",
        "time": 79.48799995938316,
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 3.359999981995672,
          "dns": -1,
          "ssl": -1,
          "connect": -1,
          "send": 0.21999999999999997,
          "wait": 72.94899997246638,
          "receive": 2.9590000049211085,
          "_blocked_queueing": 2.267999981995672
        }
      },
      {
        "_initiator": {
          "type": "other"
        },
        "_priority": "VeryHigh",
        "_resourceType": "document",
        "cache": {},
        "connection": "94621",
        "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "http://192.168.1.1/login.cgi",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "max-age=0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "117"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": "Cookie=sid=7a2fdeb886ed7ad2e8d82fb03ae9146090c19ed33cfea5326487c6b4bdaece9c:Language:turkish:id=1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "192.168.1.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "http://192.168.1.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "http://192.168.1.1/"
            },
            {
              "name": "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": "sid=7a2fdeb886ed7ad2e8d82fb03ae9146090c19ed33cfea5326487c6b4bdaece9c:Language:turkish:id=1",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "192.168.1.1",
              "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": false
            }
          ],
          "headersSize": 736,
          "bodySize": 117,
          "postData": {
            "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "text": "UserName=admin&PassWord=aGNzNTQzNio%3D&Language=turkish&x.X_HW_Token=2ee81f23402d9dedb018a978c775ea4944a35b229d3b1221",
            "params": [
              {
                "name": "UserName",
                "value": "admin"
              },
              {
                "name": "PassWord",
                "value": "aGNzNTQzNio%3D"
              },
              {
                "name": "Language",
                "value": "turkish"
              },
              {
                "name": "x.X_HW_Token",
                "value": "2ee81f23402d9dedb018a978c775ea4944a35b229d3b1221"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "OK",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Cache-control",
              "value": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "Keep-Alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Security-Policy",
              "value": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Pragma",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "Set-cookie",
              "value": "Cookie=sid=3ef92539df7b3e209b1c229285c5007549b2c4eec5f68dd1234ac49ca0fe6e14:Language:turkish:id=1;path=/;HttpOnly"
            },
            {
              "name": "Transfer-Encoding",
              "value": "chunked"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-Frame-Options",
              "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-XSS-Protection",
              "value": "1; mode=block"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": "sid=3ef92539df7b3e209b1c229285c5007549b2c4eec5f68dd1234ac49ca0fe6e14:Language:turkish:id=1",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "192.168.1.1",
              "expires": null,
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": false
            }
          ],
          "content": {
            "size": 610,
            "mimeType": "text/html",
            "compression": -12
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 430,
          "bodySize": 622,
          "_transferSize": 1052,
          "_error": null
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "192.168.1.1",
        "startedDateTime": "2023-03-20T16:30:38.465Z",
        "time": 2899.5390000054613,
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 8.06600000488013,
          "dns": -1,
          "ssl": -1,
          "connect": -1,
          "send": 0.6430000000000007,
          "wait": 2889.0549999890327,
          "receive": 1.7750000115484,
          "_blocked_queueing": 2.6150000048801303
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Watch the network page in the developer tools of your browser what follow up calls taking place after the page is shown (we can safely assume that the data you are interested in is collected later via some ajax calls) Try to interpret the calls if there is something that looks like the one you want and then in your own programm do a second call after the login on the now know "real" endpoint you are interested in amd use the collected auth info in that call from the login.

Comment: What is the response status.  Normally is 200 OK and 400/500 if error.  You may be using HTTP 1.1 (chunk mode) and getting a 100 response which means you need to send a next chunk to get more data.

Comment: The unique code generated with cookie sid is different.

Comment: You're going to need a headless browser to do anything useful.